# фиксированное колличество символов в int для поля sql server

Tags: sql-server

Как ограничить число символов в ячейке?

В типе `char` это сделать возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно ограничить именно *количество символов*, то это можно сделать следующим образом: приводим число к строке и проверяем длину.

```
create table some_table
(
    phone_number integer not null check (len(cast(phone_number as char)) < 5)
)
```

Примите во внимание, что тип `integer` может принимать максимальное значение `2147483647`. То есть этого явно недостаточно для номеров телефонов.

Можно написать и просто `len(phone_number)` - при этом будет выполняться неявное преобразование.